# Python executable application with history that "remembers" user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, user-input, persistence

I want to convert my Python script with a GUI into an executable file, but add the ability for the application to remember the last user input. For example, I want it to default to the user's last selected directory each time the user opens the application.

I came across [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282318/how-can-i-get-a-python-script-to-remember-user-input) that suggests using the `readline` or `rlwrap` library, but the documentation seems to suggest that it reads a local file.

Is there a way to have the ability "remember" user input with an executable Python application?

Comment: How do you expect an application to *remember* user input without storing it in a local file?

Comment: There's not many ways for data to persist; if you don't want to write to a local file, then what other options do you have? Writing to the cloud? Writing to RAM (which would mean that the data would not persist after a restart)? Writing to the system registry? By what physical mechanism do you want the data to be stored if not the hard drive?

Comment: Great points! I had assumed other applications somehow stored user data internally within the application, but after your comments, I realize that there are folders/flies in Program Files (and equivalent for Mac) that are created.

Is there then a standard folder/file location and format I should use?

Comment: @AdamW. there are many existing standards and practices for storing local data, but it's not really a huge deal what you choose as long as it works and isn't overcomplicated.